# html5 table displaying real time mysql data

Tags: html

In my mysql database I have a table which shows when users have logged in and when they log out. I want to create a table in html5 which shows real time whether a user is logged in or not. The table will get this data from the mysql database.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to go about doing this? Please bear in mind I am only just starting out in html5 and programming all together.

Comment: Html5 cannot talk to mysql; Do you have any particular solution for that in mind?

Comment: Either using php or node.js. But what is the better method?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look into using something like [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

You can use one of the many [MySQL Drivers](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mysql) to communicate with MySQL from Node.js.

Comment: Thanks and do you know of any newbie guides for implementing this?

Comment: You may be able to just go through http://www.nodebeginner.org/ and http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html, but it is difficult to say.

Comment: To be fair I am reading around regarding this matter and the consensus is to use PHP for this type of work. So I will look at using PHP. But thanks for your help!